# Problem when add data in Subcollection Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', idDoc, 'notes'), {
    title: noteTitle,
    body: 'comentario por defecto.',
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
});
```

[image: Error]

[image: My Databases Structure]

When I trying to add data in my sub collection 'notes'. Appear this mistake, I don't know what is happening because I using the same code reference in Firebase v9 Documentation.

Extra Note: idDoc returns me: YYwcNWMfznuwAB8eN0sU

Comment: On your last note: do you get the same problem when you call it like this: `addDoc(collection(db, 'users', 'YYwcNWMfznuwAB8eN0sU', 'notes'...`?

Answer (score 1):

you use await first see async function is nesscesssry

`addDoc(collection(db, 'Institute', 'Private', 'College'), { name:"tunio" })`

this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were in the right direction but I would recommend checking how to reference [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) and then using that reference to write data into it.

It won't hurt to check your imports and dependencies as well.

> ```
> import  { doc } from "firebase/firestore";  
>
> const messageRef = doc(db,  "rooms",  "roomA",  "messages",  "message1");
> ```

This translated to your project would be:

```
const notesRef = doc(db, 'users', idDoc, 'notes');
```

---

Next, you need to check the [Add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) section as well. The code you are using as a reference applied to your app would create a new note with an auto-generated id. In the reference, "cities" would correspond to your "notes" reference.

Finally, if you substitute this, it would look like this:

```js
const noteRef = await addDoc(collection(db, notesRef), {
    title: noteTitle,
    body: 'comentario por defecto.',
    timestamp: serverTimestamp() // You also had an extra coma here
});
console.log("Note written with ID: ", noteRef.id);
```

*The console log is optional*

Answer (score 0):

try this one for add subcollections in firebase v9

```
`function uploadData() {
    var id = 'id_' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36); //create id for uniqness

    setDoc(doc(db, "Institute", `college`, `city`, `${id}`), {
        Name: "CAted college"
    })}`
```

//if you not use id set primary as name then no need to use id only write "name" of sugeesttion that unique for data base instead of id